# Append html dynamically in layout binded to controller

Tags: html, angularjs, controller, bind

I may not be able to provide proper heading to the question but the requirement for me is to add this piece of html to my layout dynamically and attatch its click events with controller.

```
<div id="subscriber1" class="participant-video-list" >
                                <div class="participant-call-controls-div">
                                    <div data-id="vm.participantId" ng-click="vm.maximizeParticipant($event)">Maximize</div>
                                    <div data-id="vm.participantId" ng-click="vm.minimizeParticipant($event)">Minimize</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Is this possible ? If yes then how can i achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. Add it to your template with ng-if="vm.someFlag", and set the flag to true when you want it to appear in the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `ng-include` directive. This directive can include HTML from external file.
 [The explanation can be seen here.](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-include.asp)

For example:

```
<ng-include src="template"></ng-include>
```

[Work example at plunker(not my).](http://plnkr.co/edit/5ImqWj65YllaCYD5kX5E?p=preview)